# Mechanical animation

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am trying to animate a missile launcher I built.  All was going fine till I encountered the below problem.

As you will see from the images I am trying to give the missile loading container.  All of the objects are parented to each other.

First pic a 90-degree turn in the x-axis - all is good.
2nd and 3rd pic another 90-degree turn in the z-axis (downwards) and insert a keyframe.

4th Pic When I play the animation I get this weird turn before the object comes in the place I want and I do not know what is causing the problem.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: i would recommend uploading a blend file with an easy object and just your animation so we can check it out

Comment: I have added a simple blend file with interested file as suggested.  Parenting is as follows.  Missile loader is parented t its holder and the holder is parented to the joint.

Comment: is this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1OjR.gif what you wanna have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want it like my gif shows....

1. delete your last keyframe
2. set timeline to your 2nd keyframe, keyframe delta transform rotation

[image]

now set timeline to 550 again, set delta transform x to 90 and keyframe

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.  Never even noticed there was a Delta transform.  Will have to study its functions well.  I have another set of animation for this part, after this one.  Should I continue in delta from now on?

Comment: You are welcome